# using minusMinutes() in the LocalTime class in the time package

Tags: java, methods, time, parameters, java-time

I am quite new and am asking to see how to use this method. here is my problematic code...

```java
import java.time.LocalTime;

class Workingtime{
  public static void main(String[] args){

    LocalTime timeobj = LocalTime.minusMinutes();
    String subtractedtimevar = timeobj.minutesToSubtract(1);
    System.out.println(subtractedtimevar);

  }
}
```

please give me the correct use of this method with any subtraction of time as an example.

i tried to subtract 1 minute to see how the method works from the oracle literature.

thanks to those who respond.

- working monkey

Answer (score 0):

You must study the [Javadoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) for any class you want to use.

On [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html), you will not find any `minutesToSubtract` method. You can only call methods defined on that class.

You will find a [`minusMinutes`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#minusMinutes(long)) method.

Because *java.time* uses [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), the result of that method is a new `LocalTime` object. The original `LocalTime` object remains intact.

```
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now() ;
LocalTime then = now.minusMinutes( 2 ) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, the LocalTime class doesn't have a method called minutesToSubtract() or minusMinutes() that directly subtracts minutes from a LocalTime object. Instead, you can achieve this by creating a new LocalTime object with the desired time difference.

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

class Workingtime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now();
        LocalTime subtractedTime = currentTime.minus(1, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
        System.out.println("Current Time: " + currentTime);
        System.out.println("Subtracted Time: " + subtractedTime);
    }
}
```

We first obtain the current time using LocalTime.now() and store it in the currentTime variable.
Then, we subtract 1 minute from the currentTime using the minus() method along with ChronoUnit.MINUTES to specify the unit of time to subtract.